# Getting a script I found to timestamp in google-spreadsheet to work found my sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi i have been reading many help topics on writing a script to auto-date a cell when other cells are change i have found a script that says it is to work but i don't know enough to know how to change the script to work for what i want can someone break this down for me where do i need to add the sheetname,tabname,and cells i want effected. Is there anything that needs replaced.

```
function onEdit(e) {
var sheetName = 'Sheet1'; //name of the sheet the script should work on 
var colToWatch = 2 // watches for edits made in col B
var colToStamp = 1 //timestamp in col A
if (e.range.columnStart !== colToWatch || e.source.getActiveSheet()
    .getName() !== sheetName || e.value == '') return;
var writeVal = e.value !== "" ? new Date() : '';
e.source.getActiveSheet()
    .getRange(e.range.rowStart, colToStamp)
    .setValue(writeVal);
}
```

this is one of the sheets i would love to use this script in... tab name " event7" the rows i want watched are L2: N50 and new date in column O for each row

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code writing service. We don't go off-site to look to see what your requirements are and then come back and update code you copy/pasted from somewhere to meet those requirements. Read the code, make an effort to modify it yourself, and then you can ask a specific question about any problem you encounter. If you can't even make an effort, hire a contractor to make the modifications for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a different script that Auto-Dates cells in google-spreadsheet hope it helps someone else.

```
function onEdit(e) {
var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet()
if (sh.getName() !== 'Event 7' || e.range.columnStart < 12 || e.range.columnStart > 14 || e.range.rowStart < 2 || e.range.rowStart > 50) return;
sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 15)
.setValue(new Date())}
```

**this script watches L2 : N50 placing a new date stamp in column O if that row changes**

1. open script editer in the sheet you wish to use this on. copy/paste
   script.
2. change 'Event 7' to match you tab name including any
   spaceing.
3. change the ## to the columns and rows you want effected.(Count columns left to right a=1 b=2 c=3)

   - e.range.columnStart < 12  (is column L)
   - e.range.columnStart > 14  (is column N)
   - e.range.rowStart < 2  (row 2)
   - e.range.rowStart < 50 (row 50)
   - sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 15) (column O)

**Save but Don't run just edit effected cells (in my example after saving just edit a cell in L2 : N50)**

Answer (score 0):

That should do it. You need to insert the spreadsheet id and run setupMyTrigger() and hopefully this will work without too much tweaking.

```
function onMyEdit(e) 
{
  var sh=e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var shName=sh.getName();
  var col=e.range.getColumn();
  var row=e.range.getRow();

  if(shName=='event7' &&  col>11 && col<15 && row>1 && row<51)
  {
      sh.getRange(row,15).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
  }
}

function setUpMyTrigger()
{
  if(!isTrigger('onMyEdit'))//This prevents you from setting up more than one trigger at a time for the same function.
  {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('onMyEdit').forSpreadsheet('Put SpreadSheetIdHere').onEdit().create();
  }
}

function isTrigger(funcName)
{
  var r=false;
  if(funcName)
  {
    var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    var allHandlers=[];
    for(var i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++)
    {
      allHandlers.push(allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction());
    }
    if(allHandlers.indexOf(funcName)>-1)
    {
      r=true;
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```